# How do you set the ChromeDriver port in Canopy (selenium library)?

Tags: docker, f#, selenium-chromedriver, canopy-web-testing

I'm using Canopy within a Docker container and would like to specify the port to 4444 instead of the final random one assigned when calling canopy.core.start because of multiple connectivity errors *Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)* 
--or a failure to launch the driver.

```
let chromeOptions = OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-client-side-phishing-detection")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-suggestions-service")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-first-run")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--allow-insecure-localhost");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--port=4444"); // Not taking effect; see below
let chromeNoSandbox = ChromeWithOptions(chromeOptions)
canopy.configuration.chromeDir <- "."
start chromeNoSandbox
```

> Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) <--- **Multiple of these in a docker container**
>
> Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139
>   (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 36479 <-- **How to specify this?**

Comment: By the way, instead of doing `chromeOptions.AddArguemnt` and adding arguments one-by-one, opt for `chromeOptions.AddArguments` (plural, notice the _s_ at the end) which takes any `IEnumerable` of options (e.g. the most idiomatic for F#, of course, a list).

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing this!

How *Canopy* starts a *WebDriver* instance is by calling `OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("<path to the chromedriver executable on runner machine>")`. (Where, of course, this is true for all other browsers).

Problem is this method, according to the documentation returns a **random** port by definition (this is done to ensure parallel runs don't get the same port and crash. The chances of that happening are, thankfully, low).

you could try doing something like `let a = OpenQA.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("<path>")` followed by `a.Port <- <port number>`, **but** I don't know how to use the resultant `WebDriverService` as the runner of our tests.

The `port=4444` bit on the `ChromeOptions` doesn't work because this is not a Chrome (or browser, to be general) option. It is a *WebDriver* one.

I posted a question on the project's [tracker](https://github.com/lefthandedgoat/canopy/issues/481#issue-507184940). Hopefully, we'll get an answer sometime soon...